# Android SDK Bluetooth java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm implementing a little Bluetooth App in Eclipse with Android SDK and Android Bluetooth. But every time when launching with an Android Virtual Device, my app crashes. I get the following error in LogCat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1170): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter$LeScanCallback)' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime(1170): at ble.BluetoothLeService.startScanning(BluetoothLeService.java:241)
```

Here is the part of the code where LogCat said, the error must be.

```
    // BluetoothLeService - manages connections and data communicationwith    given Bluetooth LE devices.
public class BluetoothLeService extends Service {
private final static String TAG = BluetoothLeService.class.getSimpleName();

private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager;
private boolean mScanning;
private Handler mHandler;
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

   private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

    // Called when new BLE device is discovered
    // Broadcast intent is sent with following extras: device , rssi,
    // additional advertise data
    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {

        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(ACTION_DEVICE_DISCOVERED);
        broadcastIntent.putExtra(DISCOVERED_DEVICE, device);
        broadcastIntent.putExtra(RSSI, rssi);
        broadcastIntent.putExtra(SCAN_RECORD, scanRecord);

        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        Log.i("BLE service", "onLeScan - device: " + device.getAddress() + " - rssi: " + rssi);
    }
};

// Starts scanning for new BLE devices


public void startScanning(final int scanPeriod) {

    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        // Called after scanPeriod milliseconds elapsed
        // It stops scanning and sends broadcast
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mScanning = false;
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);

            Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(ACTION_STOP_SCAN);
            sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

        }
    }, scanPeriod);

    mScanning = true;
    mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);

}

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public BluetoothLeService getService() {
        return BluetoothLeService.this;
    }
}
```

I tried a lot of different things, but couldn't find a solution. Can anyone help me out?